# column value based pivot with output in multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a table :

| HostName | Application |
| --- | --- |
| SRV000001 | App1 |
| SRV000001 | App2 |
| SRV000002 | App3 |
| SRV000003 | App1 |
| SRV000003 | App4 |
| SRV000003 | App5 |

I need to pivot / group around the Hostname column so that the result is something like. As the number of columns to get is not fixed I am finding it hard to use the pivot function on this.

| HostName | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SRV000001 | App1 | App2 |  |
| SRV000002 | App3 |  |  |
| SRV000003 | App1 | App4 | App5 |

Answer (score 0):

The columns might be ennumbered by using `ROW_NUMBER()` window function in order to determine the columns titles such as `Col1, Col2..`, and then conditional aggregation might be applied through use of this query :

```
SELECT [HostName], 
       MAX(CASE WHEN [rn]=1 THEN [Application] END) AS [Col1],
       MAX(CASE WHEN [rn]=2 THEN [Application] END) AS [Col2],
       MAX(CASE WHEN [rn]=3 THEN [Application] END) AS [Col3]
  FROM( 
       SELECT *,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
              (PARTITION BY [HostName] ORDER BY [Application]) AS [rn]
         FROM [t]
      ) AS t
 GROUP BY [HostName]
```

The query might be converted to a dynamic one through the following code block :

```
DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),  @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = ( SELECT STRING_AGG('MAX(CASE WHEN [rn]='+
                                 CAST([rn] AS VARCHAR)+
                               ' THEN [Application] END) AS [Col'+
                                 CAST([rn] AS VARCHAR)+
                               ']',',') 
                FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                            (PARTITION BY [HostName] ORDER BY [HostName]) AS [rn]
                        FROM [t] ) t );

SET  @query = 
     N'SELECT [HostName],' + @cols + 
     N'  FROM( 
              SELECT *,
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                     (PARTITION BY [HostName] ORDER BY [Application]) AS [rn]
                FROM [t]
             ) AS t
        GROUP BY [HostName]';

EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=36abe07404a9db3a0be8e682449b9eed)</kbd>